# How to set UI language in English and IntelliSense hint Language in another language in Visual Studio 2012 ?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem: I want set UI of my Visual Studio 2012 in default (English) language, but also I want that IntelliSense hints about .NET types are displayed in another language. In Visual Studio 2010 it was a very simple.

I installed before localized version, after - English version, after going in to the location

> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> International Settings.

There was displayed two languages: local and english. I set language on Englist, restarting Visual Studio, and get what I wanted.

In Visual Studio 2012 this method is not working. I can only install language package. It change all in Visual Studio - UI, Intellisense hints, .NET Framework errors messages, e.t.c. How to set Visual Studio UI in English and Intellisense hints and .NET Framework errors messages in another language?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft offers [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246590.aspx) article to change UI and etc of VS 2012.

I just did all stuff from Spanish to English and I get English UI including hints and etc,

Try it. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this method will change localization for all elements in VS UI. I want that all in UI to use English localization, but IntelliSence hints use my (not English) localization simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the link does not always change the language package. It's a problem of Microsoft developers. If you want to get Visual Studio in english, please check the package language you are installing when you open the .exe file. Check that it says "ENU".

[image]

This is the correct link to Visual Studio 2015:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48157

Sometime you switch language but it download the same file, and just when you open it, you see the same language being installed, and you are thinking that you selected the corrected language, and you did, but microsoft did you gave you the right file, and only when you see in the installation title, you can know that you are installing the correct language.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012 Express, you must go to Tools > Options > International Settings> right you must select your language, if not, you can clic on the link "[get additional languages​​](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30681)"

Answer (score 1):

The *International Settings* in the VS options only seem to change the UI language, but not the IntelliSense hints.

I can't pin down any more what exactly fixed it, but I uninstalled all (in my case German) language packs from the Windows control panel that seemed to be related to the .NET framework and Visual Studio (including the ones for Office Development and the .NET Framework Targeting Pack Language Packs). After a restart of VS, the IntelliSense hints were finally in English.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, was the UI of your VS still in German, or changed to English too? If you got UI in German and IntelliSence hints in English at the same time, I guess you have found an answer and I can mark your answer as the solution. Unfortunately I can't check it on my PC anymore.

Comment: The UI was always in English (correctly so, because it was set in the options), I just wanted to have both in English. However I found out that the actual intellisense language files are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6`(or your Framework Version) within a subfolder, e.g. `de`, so it would be worth checking on them too.